# Bootstrap grid push and pull issue

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for the first time.
Trying to learned the grid-system of push and pull.

```
<header>
    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->              

    <div class ="container">
        <div class = "row">
            <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-8">
                <h1>RSisdtorante con Fusion</h1>
                <p style="padding:40px;"></p>
                <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
            </div >
            <div class = "col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <h1> hello brother</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

It does not change the html page at all. 
is it necessary to include whole code to look at the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We are not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.

Comment: Perfect explanation by davidpauljunior in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23556230/what-do-push-pull-classes-do-in-a-grid-system)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example from the bootstrap documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

The way you are using the grid classes, your divs will be full-width on `xs` screens, but on `sm` screens, the top div will be two-thirds width and the second will be one third width. Anything bigger than a small screen will be reflect this division.

If you are using Chrome, open the Developer Tools and resize your page, making it smaller, and you will see the change.

Bootstrap has a different class syntax for push and pull, read the syntax here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering